# How do I prove the following statement in my lecture notes?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Firstly, I would like to say I do not study mathematics at university however I came across the following statement in my engineering lecture notes

[Link to lecture notes, the statement of interest is highlighted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uRmrE.png)

[image]

I have attempted to find a proof online but have failed to do so therefore I hoped for a proof on this website.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your statement in the present form is false.
Take for example 
$$a_n=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}+\frac{(-1)^n}{n},$$ 
then "the magnitude of successive terms approach zero", i.e. $|a_n|\to 0$, and also "the sum of the first $n$ terms is less than the term $a_{n+1}$",
$$\sum_{i = 1}^{n} (-1)^{i+1}a_i<a_{n+1},$$
but the series 
$$\sum_{i = 1}^{\infty} (-1)^{i+1}a_i=\sum_{i = 1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{(-1)^{i+1}}{\sqrt{i}}-\frac{1}{i}\right)=-\infty$$ 
is not convergent.

Your statement seems to be related with the [alternating series test (with proof)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test), but then you need that $a_n>0$  **decreases monotonically to zero**.

Comment: I made an edit, the requirements on the sequence satisfy those of the alternating series test.

Comment: @duper21 I edited my answer.

Comment: So would it be correct to say that the highlighted statement in my lecture notes,is false ?

Comment: Yes my counterexample shows that it is false.

Comment: @MarkBennet $\sum_{i = 1}^{\infty} (-1)^{i+1}a_i$ with "my" $a_n>0$ IS an alternating series.

Comment: @RobertZ apologies, I see it now. I think the condition should be on the absolute value of the sum being less than the absolute value on the next term. There is an implicit assumption that the sum is positive.

Comment: And now I do see that this is not simply fixed.

Comment: @MarkBennet I agree, it's rather difficult to "save" that statement.

Answer (score 1):

I am missing some requirements on the sequence $(a_n)$. As it stands, it is not true. Take $a_i=1$ for all $i$.

Comment: I made an edit, I hoped to prove the sum converges if the $n^{th}$ partial sum is less than the term $a_{n+1}$ when the requirements on the sequence satisfy those of the alternating series test.

Comment: I apologise for the constant edits, I have included a link to the actual lecture notes so that it may be easier to understand.

Comment: The condition is applied to an alternating series. $a_i=1$ is not alternating.